# How generate tiles 3x3 with im4java?

Tags: imagemagick, im4java

can you help me with im4java? I need to generate tiles 3x3 from 9 jpg-picture. How do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know im4java, but in ImageMagick command line you can do that as follows. I will use the same JPG picture 9 timed for simplicity.

```
montage lena.jpg -duplicate 8 -tile 3x3 -geometry +0+0 lena9a.jpg
```

[image]

Alternately,

```
convert lena.jpg \
\( -clone 0 -duplicate 2 +append \) \
\( -clone 0 -duplicate 2 +append \) \
\( -clone 0 -duplicate 2 +append \) \
-delete 0 \
-append lena9b.jpg
```

[image]

Just replace my duplicate commands with your other images